# VB Script for Automating File Creation (On-Demand Opportunity!)

Tags: vbscript, automation

I'm a Financial person and not quite the VB scripting guru, but I'm wondering if someone could create a sample vb script based on my requirements.

Whoever provides the solution first and the solution works on my end will have an opportunity (paid of course) to create more of these custom solutions where I work at.  It wouldn't be full-time position, but more of an On-Demand opportunity.

Requirements:
To be able to read a text file that is delimited by comma and has various entries

For example, in text file...
SEC_E_All_Entities,HSII,SL_DIMENSION,READWRITE,@IDESCENDANTS,N
SEC_E_ENT_Americas,Americas,SL_DIMENSION,READ,MEMBER,N

And perform the following...

1. Create an XML file per entry, based on the first value

For example:
Create SEC_E_All_Entities.XML and SEC_E_ENT_Americas.XML

2. Within each file, write the contents where you can see how the values match each tag.

For example:

In the SEC_E_All_Entities.XML file, write...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<acls>
<acl>
 <name>SEC_E_All_Entities</name>
 <objectName>HSII</objectName>
 <objectType>SL_DIMENSION</objectType>
 <accessMode>READWRITE</accessMode>
 <flag>@IDESCENDANTS</flag>
 <isUser>N</isUser>
</acl>
</acls>
```

In the SEC_E_All_Americas.XML file, write...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<acls>
<acl>
 <name>SEC_E_ENT_Americas</name>
 <objectName>Americas</objectName>
 <objectType>SL_DIMENSION</objectType>
 <accessMode>READ</accessMode>
 <flag>MEMBER</flag>
 <isUser>N</isUser>
</acl>
</acls>
```

Regards,
Judy

Comment: Will the csv file's structure remain static? As in, each line will have 6 values?

Comment: That's correct, Pankaj.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample script

```
'Step 1 - Read the file and store the content in memory (an array)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\StackOverflow\acls.txt", 1)
arrFile = Split(objFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf) 'will store one line in each array index
objFile.Close

'Step 2 - Load the XML template in memory 
Set xmlTemplate = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
With xmlTemplate
    .ValidateOnParse = True
    .Async = False
    .LoadXML "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>" & _
                "<acls>" & _
                    "<acl>" & _
                        "<name></name>" & _
                        "<objectName></objectName>" & _
                        "<objectType></objectType>" & _
                        "<accessMode></accessMode>" & _
                        "<flag></flag>" & _
                        "<isUser></isUser>" & _
                    "</acl>" & _
                "</acls>"    
End With

'Step 3 - Load the relevant fields for which the data is to be set from csv file
Set nodeFields = xmlTemplate.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/acls/acl/*")

'Step 4 - Read each line of text and create XML
For i = LBound(arrFile) To UBound(arrFile)
    arrLine = Split(arrFile(i), ",") 'will split the line into various fields (to be used to create the xml)
    For j = LBound(arrLine) To UBound(arrLine) 'set values for each field
        nodeFields(j).Text = arrLine(j)
    Next
    Set xmlNew = xmlTemplate
    xmlNew.Save objFSO.BuildPath("C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\StackOverflow\", nodeFields(0).Text & ".xml") 'copy modified template as new xml file
    Set xmlNew = Nothing    
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Pankaj!  I'm going to have one of our Business Analysts set this up for us and get back to you on our testing.  Many thanks!

Comment: No worries. Be aware that this is a basic script with no error handling - also I only went by the file structure you provided.

Comment: This worked, Pankaj!  Brilliant!  We have more work for you.  How can we get in touch with you?